# RAM buffer in /proc/iomem

Tags: linux, kernel

I can see several "RAM buffer" regions in /proc/iomem. What is the purpose of the "RAM buffer" region?

```
$ cat /proc/iomem
...
79826000-79ffffff : System RAM
7a000000-7bffffff : RAM buffer
80000000-909ffffe : PCI Bus 0000:00
80000000-8fffffff : 0000:00:02.0
90000000-903fffff : 0000:00:02.0
90400000-904fffff : PCI Bus 0000:01
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your computer you will probably find that some of your ram is stolen by things like graphics cards. The ram buffer is there to prevent your application from using that stolen address space, or at least to indicate that the address space points somewhere else

It is a buffer in the sense that it takes up space, not a buffer in the sense of buffering IO requests between your CPU and memory. In point of fact, we use to have thing's like a "northbridge" controller that would have buffered data between memory and CPU, but that no longer exists and would not have shown up in /proc/iomem.